# How to fix incorrect html tags inside a string using python?

Tags: python, html, chatgpt-api

So I am generating articles containing HTML tags from openai's API using python. Articles are long and mostly I get correct results  but sometimes HTML tags are not correct, here is an example :

```
<h3><strong>1. Gaze:</strong></h 3 >
<p><strong>Gaze</ strong>. is a free and easy-to-use video streaming app , supporting both live and pre-recorded content. It supports up to 10 people joining a single session at once, with synchronized video playback for all users. Additionally, Gaze offers its own messaging service so you can chat during the viewing experience.</p>
 
<h3><strong>2. Chrono:</strong></h 3 >
```

How can I fix these HTML tags? I have already used bs4 but it is separating tags on separate lines, that's not what I want.

is there any other solution for this using python?

I have tried bs4 but not get good results...

Comment: I tried your above syntax with bs4 and it worked perfectly. Can you share more about the issue faced with bs4.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DevAKS,  with bs4 tags get generated in separate lines I don't want that. I only want to correct html tags , like </h 3 > should be </h3>

Answer (score 0):

The HTML example in your question needs to be corrected due to the extra spaces in the closing tags. You can fix these malformed closing tags by simply removing all their spaces. Here is an example:

```py
import re

def remove_spaces_from_closing_tags(html):
    fixed_html = ""
    # Regular Expression sets apart tags and other content
    for tag, other_content in re.findall(r'(<[^>]*>)|([^<]*)', html):
        if tag:
            # If it is a closing tag then remove spaces, otherwise leave it as is
            fixed_html += re.sub(r'\s+', r'', tag) if '/' in tag else tag
        if other_content:
            # Leave other content as is
            fixed_html += other_content
    return fixed_html



# Input malformed HTML
html = """
<h3><strong>1. Gaze:</strong></h 3 >
<p><strong>Gaze</ strong>. is a free and easy-to-use video streaming app , supporting both live and pre-recorded content. It supports up to 10 people joining a single session at once, with synchronized video playback for all users. Additionally, Gaze offers its own messaging service so you can chat during the viewing experience.</p>
 
<h3><strong>2. Chrono:< / st rong ></h 3 >
"""

print(remove_spaces_from_closing_tags(html))
```

This example code will output:

```html
<h3><strong>1. Gaze:</strong></h3>
<p><strong>Gaze</strong>. is a free and easy-to-use video streaming app , supporting both live and pre-recorded content. It supports up to 10 people joining a single session at once, with synchronized video playback for all users. Additionally, Gaze offers its own messaging service so you can chat during the viewing experience.</p>
 
<h3><strong>2. Chrono:</strong></h3>
```

You can fix malformed closing tags by using the `remove_spaces_from_closing_tags` function defined above. Your example does not show any malformed opening tags, but keep in mind that you cannot use the same approach for malformed opening tags if you have those as well. For example, removing all spaces from the malformed opening tag, such as `<h 3 class="some-class">`, would not fix it. Therefore, the `remove_spaces_from_closing_tags` function fixes only the closing tags with extra whitespaces, similar to those in your example HTML.